# How can I use IEnumerable to make variables from json input from an http call?

Tags: c#, json, httprequest

I am trying to use an application to call an api, and to return data unique a user. I've made a separate class for the imported items:

```
public class ItemList
{
     public class Task : IEnumerable<Task>
     {
          public string variable1 { get; set; }
          ....
     }

     public IEnumerator<Task> GetEnumerator()
     { 
          return taskList.GetEnumerator();
     }

     IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
     {
          return taskList.GetEnumerator();
     }
}
```

In a separate class, I make an http call that returns json to be sorted into tasks.

```
WebRequest requestObjGet = WebRequest.Create(url);
//headers, etc
responseObjGet = (HttpWebResponse)requestObjGet.GetResponse();

using (Stream stream = responseObjGet.GetResponseStream())
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
    strResultTest=sr.ReadToEnd();

    ItemList userActiveItemData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemList>(strResultTest);

    foreach(Task item in userActiveITemData)
    { 
       // DO A THING
    }
}
```

Here I get an error that foreach cannot operate on variables of type `ItemList` because `ItemList` does not contain a public instance for `GetEnumerator`.

Can someone help me run this loop?

Comment: And why can you just serialize, deserialize List<Task>? As: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Task>>(strResultTest);

Having that serialized as: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<Task>() {});

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. I am not serializing any object, but am trying to extract data from an http json call. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

The class `ItemList` is not needed. You are trying to implement `IEnumerable` interface,  it could be replaced by a simple `List<Task>` or `Task[]` which already implements `IEnumerable`.

You could deserialize the JSON into a model that corresponds to the structure of the JSON:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TasksModel>(strResultTest);

foreach(Task item in model.Tasks)
{ 
   // DO A THING
}
```

The model:

```
public class TasksModel
{
    [JsonProperty("tasks")]
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
public class Task
{
    [JsonProperty("variable1")]
    public string Variable1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("variable2")]
    public string Variable2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When I do this, I get an exception 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object(eg{"name":"value"})... because the type requires a JSON array.

Comment: Could you share also example of the json please?

Comment: {"tasks": [{"variable1":"value1", "variable2":"value2"}, {"variable1":"value1.2", "variable2":"value2.2"}]}

Comment: updated the answer, now there is a class `TasksModel` that holds the `Tasks` property. For deriving a class model from json there are also online tools such as https://quicktype.io/csharp/.

Comment: This gives me the error "Cannot implicitly convert type '...Classes.ItemList.TasksModel' to '...Classes.ItemList.Task[]'.

Comment: it is fixed now, the corrected version is `var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TasksModel>(strResultTest);`

Comment: Now I cannot loop through these items because 'ItemList.TasksModel' does not contain "GetEnumerator'. I thought this method avoided using Enumerator?

Comment: To loop through the tasks, use `foreach(Task item in model.Tasks)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `ItemList` as an `IEnumerable<Task>`, then I think we need to move your `Task` class out to the same scope as `ItemList`, and make `ItemList` implement `IEnumerable<Task>`.

In the code below I've renamed `Task` to `MyTask` in order to avoid confusion with the well known `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` class.

```
public class MyTask
{
    public string variable1 { get; set; }
}

public class ItemList : IEnumerable<MyTask>
{
    public IEnumerable<MyTask> taskList = new List<MyTask>();

    public IEnumerator<MyTask> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return taskList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return taskList.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many online tools that will convert your JSON response into an appropriate C# model/s so that all you need to do is call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` to get access to the IEnumerable.

Assuming that the response from the webserver is in this format `{"tasks": [{"variable1":"value1", "variable2":"value2"}, {"variable1":"value1.2", "variable2":"value2.2"}]}` we get the following C# Models (https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp):

```
    public partial class TaskModel
    {
        public Task[] Tasks { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Task
    {
        public string Variable1 { get; set; }
        public string Variable2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Note that since `TaskModel` is the root you can call it whatever you like.

We can then get access to the tasks in a foreach loop like so:

```
            WebRequest requestObjGet = WebRequest.Create("http://someurl.com");

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)requestObjGet.GetResponse();

            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                var strResultTest = sr.ReadToEnd();

                TaskModel taskModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TaskModel>(strResultTest);

                foreach (var task in taskModel.Tasks)
                {
                    // DO A THING
                }
            }
```